# Python Error: Could not find root within given tolerance?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, sympy, root

I'm trying to find the roots of an equation `f` that is the result of the determinant of a matrix. Arriving at this equation was simple, I generated the following code:

```
from sympy import *
from math import sqrt

def Rec_Coef(n, l, Q, rho, i):
    r1 = (1/2)*(1+sqrt(1-4*Q**2))
    r2 = (1/2)*(1-sqrt(1-4*Q**2))
    
    b = (rho*r1**2)/(r1-r2)
    
    if i == 1:
        q = (1/2)*(3+sqrt(9+16*Q**2*(l-1)*(l+2)))
    if i == 2: 
        q = (1/2)*(3-sqrt(9+16*Q**2*(l-1)*(l+2)))
        
    A = l*(l+1)    
        
    alpha = (n**2 + 2*(b+1)*n + 2*b + 1)*r1
    beta = (-2 + r2)*n**2 + (-2 - 2*b*(2-r2) - 4*rho*r1**2 + 6*r2)*n + (q - 2*(rho**2)*(r1**3) - 4*rho*r1**2*(1+b) - 2*b**2*(2-r1**(-1)) - r1*A - (3-2*b)*r2)
    gamma = (1+r2)*n**2 + (2*rho*r1*(1+2*r2)+2*b*(1+r2)-10*r2)*n + (rho*r1*(2 -12*r2 + (rho+2*b)*(1+2*r2)) -1 -q -2*b*(1+3*r2) + b**2*(16 + 8*r2 - (15 - 38*r2 + 26*r2**2)*r1**(-3)) + (A+13)*r2)
    delta = (-n**2 + 2*(3 - rho -b)*n - (9 + 4*rho*b - 6*b - 6*rho))*r2
    
    return alpha, beta, gamma, delta

N=4

α = []
β = []
γ = []
δ = []

l = 2 
Q = 0.2
i = 2

rho = symbols("")

for j in range(N):
    alpha, beta, gamma, delta = simplify(Rec_Coef(j, 2, 0.2, rho, 2))
    α.append(alpha)
    β.append(beta)
    γ.append(gamma)
    δ.append(delta)  

array = [[0]*(N+1) for row in range(N)]

array[0][0] = β[0]
array[0][1] = α[0]
array[1][0] = γ[1]
array[1][1] = β[1]
array[1][2] = α[1]

for i in range(2,N):
    array[i][i-1] = γ[i] - (array[i-1][i-1]/array[i-1][i-2])*δ[i]
    array[i][i] = β[i] - (array[i-1][i]/array[i-1][i-2])*δ[i]
    array[i][i+1] = α[i] 
    
matrix_aux = simplify(Matrix(array))

M_aux = [[0]*(N) for row in range(N)] 

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        M_aux[i][j]=(array[i][j])  

matrix = Matrix(M_aux)

f = matrix.det()
```

So I tried to find the roots in a few ways:

**First**

I used the `mpmath` function, turned my symbolic equation into a numerical equation, and then I guessed at the value. The reference value is `(-0.17792, -0.74734*I)`.

```
import mpmath as mp

f = lambdify(rho, matrix.det())

mp.findroot(f, -0.17-0.75j)
```

However, I got the following error:

`ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (2.01839854512653723801e-14 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19) Try another starting point or tweak arguments.`

**Second**

I used the solve function

```
f = matrix.det()
sol = solve(f, rho)
sol = [s.n() for s in sol]
for s in sol:
    print(s)
```

But this time, even with a low number of iterations used at the beginning of the code (`N=4`), the cell keeps loading without stopping and does not generate any result or code.

How can I solve this problem and generate the complex roots easily?

Comment: In beta = (-2 + r2)*n**2 + (-2 - 2*b*(2-r2) - 4*rho*r1**2 + 6*r2)*n + (q - 2*(rho**2)*(r1**3) - 4*rho*r1**2*(1+b) - 2*b**2*(2-r1**(-1)) - r1*A - (3-2*b)*r2)
You switched 'r1' and 'r2'. Specifically, the term -4*rho*r1**2 should be -4*rho*r2**2.

Comment: I tried switching, but the errors were still the same. Why did you think the error was in r1 and r2?

Comment: Cuz I don't know anything about matrixs, so I asked ChatGPT, and put what it suggested in a comment, in case it helped.

Comment: Btw... ChatGPT has a Python API that you can apply to use for free. Its pretty fun.

Comment: It's a good idea. Unfortunately it didn't work but I'll try to use the GPT chat too. Thanks

Comment: @KovyJacob please, pretty please with a cherry on top. Whenever you use ChatGPT, tell us at the beginning of the post. Your current behavior shows that: 1. you have absolutely no idea what you are talking about; 2. you don't care in investing the time to understand the underlying problem. 3. you assume that ChatGPT is actually capable of doing high level math. All of these points are bad enough when considering them alone...

Comment: @Davide_sd Regarding point 1, I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Regarding point 2, its less that I don't care to learn advanced mathematics to help someone, its more that I don't have time. Regarding point 3, I think I understand what ChatGPT is and isn't capable of, what it is, and how it works. I, however, do believe that it can sometimes give the correct answer. The more complicated the question, the less likely, obviously, as it has less data - but it is possible. Regarding your point that I should say in the beginning - I accept that, that's a very good point. Thanks!

Comment: @KovyJacob point 1 means exactly that you know nothing about the scope of OP's question. And because you "don't have the time to learn advanced math", you should refrain yourself to dispense suggestions about topics that clearly you know nothing about. Yet, here you are, suggesting modifications, pointing OP on a completely wrong path, wasting OP's time (and any other future readers) because you assumed that ChatGPT is the solution to every problem. Even worst, by not mentioning ChatGPT on the your first comment, you took credit of everyone else work, which is bad enough on its own.

Comment: @Davide_sd I get your point and accept it, about talking about something I don't know about and wasting the questioner's time. I, however, do not assume that ChatGPT has the answer to every question - if I did, I would have put it in an answer, and not a comment. Regarding your last point, I think that's a bit silly - its a totally original answer, its no different than any answer anybody gives on stackoverflow. Obviously humans have the ability to think while ChatGPT can't, but they are still both solely based on other people's work and knowledge.

Comment: @KovyJacob how is it copying and pasting a sentence from a bot "original"? What's "original" about it? Did you really learn something about it? Did you invest the time to check if the bot was actually telling something useful? Of course not. The difference is that we, as StackOverflowers, try to give our best answers or suggestions, motivating them in order to share knowledge, not sharing some random BS coming out from a bot which you clearly don't understand its limitation. There are definitely things that ChatGPT is excellent at: advanced math is currently not one of them.

Comment: @Davide_sd Again, I think I understand the limitations of ChatGPT pretty well. But I mean its original, as it is a unique one-of-a-kind text, that never existed and never will exist again.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying that I have no idea what problem you are trying to solve, hence I'm going to assume that your equation `f` is built correctly.
Also, I'm unable to solve your problem, but hopefully you'll gain some insight about why your attempts failed.

To gain more intuition about the function, I plotted its absolute value in the complex plane using the [sympy plot backends module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/):

```py
import numpy as np
plot_complex(f, (rho, -2-2j, 2+2j), threed=True, backend=KB,
             tz=lambda t: np.log(t)/10, n=500)
```

[image]

Note that the above command evaluates the function over 500*500=250000 points. Watch out for memory consumption! In the above picture, every spike towards the bottom is a zero.

Looking closer in the following region, and increasing a lot the resolution of the plot (3000*3000=9M evaluation points, don't run this command as it consumes over 15GB of memory):

```py
plot_complex(f, (rho, -0.1-1j, -0.35-0.75j), threed=True, backend=KB,
             tz=lambda t: np.log(t)/30, n=3000)
```

[image]

See that noise? Let's zoom in:

[image]

In this region, it appears that your functions has "infinitely many zeros" and "infinitely many saddle points". This is a nightmare situation: no matter your initial condition, I believe it's impossible to find a zero with any numerical algorithm, let alone symbolic algorithms like `solve` or `solveset`. The distance between zeros is sooo small that I don't see how an algorithm can properly resolve the situation... Maybe `findroot` has some option to specify the tolerance???

By the way, sympy's `nsolve` is a wrapper to mpmath's `findroot`, so you can avoid the lambdification step!

Now, let's zoom into a different region:

```py
plot_complex(log(f), (rho, -0.65-0.95j, -0.6-0.9j), threed=True, backend=KB,
             tz=lambda t: np.log(t)/100, n=3000)
```

[image]

See that noise? Let's zoom in a little bit:

[image]

It appears that this is a region with infinitely many zeros, hence infinitely many saddle points... Again, a nightmare...